# Moving files to a directory

Tags: bash

I want to *move all files matching a certain pattern* in the current directory to another directory.

For example, how would I move all the files starting with `nz` to a directory called `foobar`? I tried using `mv` for that, but it didn't work out well.

Comment: How is writing a bash script to do this not programming related?

Comment: how is writing a bash script necessary to solve his problem?

Comment: you don't need a bash script for this... not programming related

Comment: @Neil: Fair enough, I tend to need to do similar things for more complex pattern matching that I forgot the simple way! D'Oh.

Comment: There was no mention of a bash script, just the bash tag. Anyway, the answer is there below :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find . | grep "your_pattern" | xargs mv destination_directory
```

Does the following:

- Finds all files in the current directory
- Filters them according to your pattern
- Moves all resulting files to the destination directory

Comment: Don't grep filenames.  Especially not with find(1): it has -name.  Also don't use xargs without -0.  Especially not with find(1): it has -exec.

Comment: Except for the fact that find can search for names what could go wrong with grepping filenames?

Comment: I cannot understand why this was accepted and upvoted. How is this supposed to work? `xargs` will execute a command of the form `mv dest/dir src1 src2 src3 ...` but the syntax of `mv` is `mv src1 src2 src3 ... dest/dir`. For the remaining part of the command I'm totally with Ihunath. @B.E. grepping filenames as done here assumes that each filename corresponds to exactly one line. In linux you can have linebreaks inside a filename.

Answer (score 8):

`mv nz* foobar` should do it.

Answer (score 6):

mv nz* foobar/

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, though if you have any directories beginning with nz it will move those too.

```
for files in nz*
do
mv $files foobar
done
```

Edit: As shown above this totally over the top. However, for more complex pattern matches you might do something like:

```
for files in `ls | grep [regexp]`
do
mv $files foobar
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "mmv", which is installed on most Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

`mv nz* foobar/`

- **mv** - will move or rename file
- **nz** - will get all the items that start with the "nz"
- **foobar/** - is the directory where all items will go into