# usage error when moving files of one extension to a directory

Tags: bash, grep

I have files with extension .mp3 that are in different folders within a directory, and I need to move them all to one directory to work with. I have looked at multiple tutorials and questions on SO, and no matter what I try, I either get

```
    usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
    mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

or "No such file or directory".

There are way too many to into each individual folder, but for now I cd into one of the folders. With this:

```
    mv *.mp3 /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media
```

I get the "usage" error above. I looked at [Moving files to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776202/moving-files-to-a-directory) and tried:

```
    find . | grep ".mp3" | xargs mv /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media
```

and get same error.

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct syntax? Also, will I be able to extract the mp3 files and move them if I'm in a directory that contains the directory with the files, but not in that directory itself? I appreciate insights into this. Thanks.

EDIT: A major part of this issue was that the path when using /Volumes starts with /Volumes. I was doing /Users/myname/Volumes and that was one reason I had so much trouble.

Comment: `mv -t path/to/target/dir *.mp3`

Comment: I got mv: illegal option -- t with that command

Comment: `-t` is supported by the `mv` implementation from GNU coreutils but not by most implementations from BSD derivates. I'm a bit astounded that `mv *.mp3 target/dir` did not work, but not so much that the `xargs` failed - the linked answer is so wrong in my opinion, no idea why it got accepted and upvoted. I'm gonna complain right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the way you're using `xargs` is that by default, `xargs` will *append* the arguments to the end of the command string you've provided it. So you'll end up running a bunch of `mv` commands that look like this:

```
mv /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media foo.mp3
```

You can fix that by telling `xargs` where to place the arguments within the command:

```
<other commands> | xargs -I{} mv {} /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media
```

The `-I` option lets you provide any arbitrary string as a placeholder for where the args should go. I used `{}` just because that seems to be the conventional token that you see used in similar contexts (such as with the `-exec` option of `find`, as shown below).

But there's an easier way to do it, using the `find` command's `-exec` option:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec mv {} /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media \;
```

Also note the `-name '*.mp3'` part, which lets you get rid of the `| grep ".mp3"` part.

Lastly, just to be safe, I'd personally put a `/` at the end of your destination path. If the `media` directory doesn't exist in `/Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder`, or if a non-directory item (such as a regular file or a symlink) named `media` exists in that location, then the `find` command above will happily just move all your mp3 files, one at a time, to that folder, creating a *file* named `media` there each time. And you will have lost *all* of your mp3 files except for the last one, which will now be a file named `media`.

However, with a trailing `/`, if `media` is not a directory, the `mv` commands will fail with an error saying so. So the revised command would be:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec mv {} /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media/ \;
```

**Update**: Per Gordon Davisson's comment below, you should also consider adding `-i` or `-n` to the `mv` command, to avoid accidentally overwriting files with duplicate names. For example, if you have `a/foo.mp3` and `b/foo.mp3`, the above command will overwrite one with the other. The `-i` option will cause `mv` to prompt you to confirm each file move, whereas the `-n` option (a.k.a. `--no-clobber`) will prevent `mv` from overwriting a file if a file with the same name already exists.

Comment: That's exactly what I way thinking. Please comment under [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776239/6770384) this command was taken from. I have no idea how it got accepted.

Comment: @Socowi It looks like someone already said as much in a comment under that answer.

Comment: You need an escaped semicolon to terminate find's  `-exec ...` sequence. Also, I strongly recommend using either `mv -i` or `mv -n` on bulk moves like this, to avoid silent & irreversible data loss if there are any duplicate filenames (or if the target directory doesn't exist & a trailing slash wasn't used).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Well spotted. Thanks.

Comment: I terminated the end of that with a semicolon but got the error: find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

Comment: @topplethepat You need to escape the semicolon. Otherwise, the shell interprets it as a command separator and `find` never sees the semicolon.

Comment: @MikeHolt I have a trailing slash per your comment and then added another one to escape the semicolon like this: find . -name '*.mp3' -exec mv {} /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media//;    Still getting error. What am I missing here?

Comment: @topplethepat You need a (single) forward-slash at the end of the path, then a space, then a backslash before the semicolon. You could also put quotes around the semicolon to get the same effect (i.e. `find . -name '*.mp3' -exec mv {} /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media/ ';'`).

Comment: @topplethepat You need a forward slash (`/`) at the end of your destination path so that `mv` knows it's supposed to be a directory, and a backwards slash (`\\``) to terminate the `-exec` clause of the `find` command. There should be a space between the end of the path and the escaped semicolon.

Comment: OK. Almost there. Now the terminal shows all those files but for each it says "No such file or directory" for the target directory. I am currently in the directory that is one above the media directory. So my expression was: find . -name '*.mp3' -exec mv {} /media/ ';' I also tried it with the full path starting with /Users and got the same. Why is not finding it?

Comment: @topplethepat What is the actual path to the target directory? If you use it with `ls` (e.g. `ls /media/`), does that find it?

Comment: @topplethepat If the `media` directory does not exist, create it with `mkdir` first. The `mv` command will not create it for you. You can also use the `-p` option to `mv` (if your `mv` supports it). That way you can do `mkdir -p /Users/myname/Volumes/LaCie/model/folder/media/`, and it will ensure that every directory within that path is created.

Comment: @MikeHolt It is created already, is empty, and if I do ls in the directory I'm in it shows it. But if I do ls /media/ it doesn't find it. Neither that or ls /Users/full path/media/ finds it either.

Comment: You may have some strange permissions thing going on, where perhaps you lack  permissions in one of those intermediate directories. Try doing an `ls -l` on each directory, one at a time, from `/Users` on down, and make sure you have read and execute permissions. You should also have write permissions on the final directory (`media`), so that you can move files there. Also, if `find` is encountering directories where you don't have appropriate permissions, that may also be causing errors.

Comment: For example, let's say there's a subdirectory named `readonly` that you contains some mp3 files, but you only have read and execute permissions on it. In order to move an mp3 file out of that directory, you will also need write permissions on that directory.

Comment: Thanks that was useful.Looks like the issue is /Volumes because when I do /Users/myname/Volumes that's when I get "No such file or directory".

Comment: @topplethepat You can drag a file or folder from the Finder into a Terminal window, and it'll paste in the correct full path to the item.

Comment: That is an awesome tip.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are different implementations and versions of `mv`. You can check the allowed syntax of your version using `man mv`.

- If you have GNU `mv` you could use `mv -t target/dir *.mp3`.
- Most implementations should support `mv *.mp3 target/dir`.
- If your `mv` only supports the absolute minimum of `mv source target` with exactly one source and one target file you can use the following command which should always work if `target/dir/` exists.

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "target/dir/$i"; done
```

Comment: I strongly recommend `mv -i` or `mv -n` for bulk moves like this.